# Echo IP Location from txt

Tags: batch-file, ping, nslookup

I am currently trying to ping a list of hostnames, preferably one at a time, and then use nslookup on that hostname. If the hostname in nslookup matches up with the hostname first used, then I would like to use the IP to check against another file (called home.txt) that would contain the location.

What I have so far:

```
@Echo Off
If '%1'=='' GOTO Syntax
Echo Running Script and Saving Results to Results.CSV
Echo Script Run %date% %time% >> Results.csv
For /F %%i in (%1) do Call :StartPing %%i
Goto :eof

:StartPing
PING %1 -n 1        | FIND /i "TTL" > nul && goto Success
PING %1 -n 1        | FIND /i "timed" > nul && goto Timedout
PING %1 -n 1 -w 400 | FIND /i "TTL" > nul || goto ErrorMsg

:Success
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping %1 ^| find /i "TTL"') do set Address=%%a
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -a %Address::=% ^| find /i "pinging"') do set HostName=%%a
set IPAddress=%Address::=%
echo %1, %IPAddress%,%Hostname%
echo %1, %IPAddress%,%Hostname% >> Results.csv

NSLOOKUP %IPAddress% | FIND /i "Name" = "%Hostname%" goto home

:home
echo %IPAddress% home.txt

Goto :EOF

:Timedout
Echo %1, Request timed out.
Echo %1, Request timed out. >> Results.csv

:ErrorMsg
Echo %1, Ping request could not find host.
Echo %1, Ping request could not find host. >> Results.csv
goto :eof

:Syntax
echo . . .
goto :eof
```

An example of what home.txt might contain:

```
10.102.6.43 = 2J
```

IE, just a bunch of IP ranges mapped to office locations.

Ideally, the script should then make a popup box showing the location of the IP address, or just echo it on-screen.

Any ideas?

Made some changes and tested a few things, here is what i have so far.

```
@echo Off
@cls
if '%1'=='' GOTO Syntax
echo Running Script and Saving Results to Results.CSV
echo Script Run %date% %time% >> Results.csv
for /F %%i in (%1) do Call :StartPing %%i
goto :EOF

:StartPing
PING %1 -n 1| FIND /i "TTL" > nul && goto Success
PING %1 -n 1| FIND /i "timed" > nul && goto Timedout
PING %1 -n 1 -w 400 | FIND /i "TTL" > nul || goto ErrorMsg

:Success
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('ping %1 ^| find /i "TTL"') do set Address=%%a
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -a %Address::=% ^| find /i "pinging"') do set HostName=%%a

set IPAddress=%Address::=%

for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('nslookup %IPAddress%^|find /i "Name"') do set fqdn=%%b

echo %1, %IPAddress%,%Hostname%
echo %1, %IPAddress%,%Hostname% >> Results.csv
goto :EOF

:Timedout
Echo %1, Request timed out.
Echo %1, Request timed out. >> Results.csv

:ErrorMsg
Echo %1, Ping request could not find host.
Echo %1, Ping request could not find host. >> Results.csv
goto :EOF

:Syntax
echo . . .
goto :EOF

:EOF
echo this is the END OF FILE
pause
```

Every time I run hh.bat host.txt, everything runs fine until it hits the nslookup part, then it creates between 1500 and 3000 processes in windows task manager. without the NSLOOKUP part hh.bat works fine.

I had the nslookup part in a separate script called nslookup.bat which worked fine for a little while, and now it does not want to work. create that amount of processes everytime...

testing in a Hyper-V environment with 3 windows 7 pcs and a DC.

Comment: i dont use windows all that often, but iirc couldnt this be done easier with a power shell script?

Comment: it probably could, but my knowledge of powershell is even less than cmd